# Building a function to read CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to Python and building a function to read CSV. I am trying to use the `pandas.read_csv()` inside my function,and while the code gets compiled-i dont see the dataset (I know its an overkill, but am trying to learn it using a trial and error method).

```
>>> def CSV(filename):
        dataset=pd.read_csv(filename)
```

I expect that when i run `CSV('abc.csv')`, it should create a df in my variable explorer. Unfortunately, the function gets compiled, but nothing is there

```
def CSV(filename):
    dataset=pd.read_csv(filename)

CSV('banking.csv')
```

Comment: You don't need a function, and all you've done is define a variable... Why are you expecting output?

Comment: add `return dataset` in your function.

Comment: *the function gets complicated*... Can you please [edit] your question with a [mcve]?

Comment: @cricket_007 Except when he'd have to do that one line initialization like a hundred times in his program.

Comment: @AakashVerma Because `pd.read_csv('banking.csv')` is that much more to type than `CSV('banking.csv')`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not now exactly, but what if later he has different params or return a transformed version after each initialization - He can later utilize this apparently useless function to make that possible.

Comment: @AakashVerma Yes, but for the code shown, it is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example, taken from [Read the Docs: Variables and Scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html), illustrates the issue that you're experiencing -- `dataset` was created in your `CSV` function, but no longer exists outside of the scope of that function:

```
# This is a global variable
a = 0

if a == 0:
    # This is still a global variable
    b = 1

def my_function(c):
    # this is a local variable
    d = 3
    print(c)
    print(d)

# Now we call the function, passing the value 7 as the first and only parameter
my_function(7)

# a and b still exist
print(a)
print(b)

# c and d don't exist anymore -- these statements will give us name errors!
print(c)
print(d)
```

In this example, variable `d` is similar to your `dataset` variable -- it's trashed as soon as execution of the function is complete.

Instead:

```
def CSV(filename):
    return pd.open_csv(filename)

df = CSV('banking.csv')
```

will create a DataFrame variable `df` that you can view in variable explorer.

Comment: Thanks much dav3ypants...you understood the question and actually made me understand ...Have a good weekend!!

Comment: Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if you feel it best addresses your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
def CSV(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(filename)

df = CSV('banking.csv')
```